# How to pass a row value in button click event?

Tags: java, html, jsp, onclick

I have the following code on my jsp file. In the two columns displayed, one column is a value and the other is a button. I want to modify the below code to pass the value in the row for which the button was clicked into a java file. The java file will basically utilize the passed value.

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>File ID</th>
<th>Generate Key</th>
</tr>
<%
 Connection con = DbConnector.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement pstm = null;
 String sql = "select u.uniquserid, t.filename, t.status, t.cloud, t.date_, t.report, t.FileID from transaction t join user u on u.userid = t.user order by t.date_ desc;";
 pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) { %>

 <tr>
   <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
        <% if (rs.getString(3).contains("s")) {%>
        <%request.getSession().setAttribute("PassFID", rs.getString(7));%>
   <td><input type="button" value='Generate Key' onclick=""></input></td>
   <%} else {%>
   <td></td>                                            
   <%}%>
 </tr>
 <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly when you say value in the row for which the button was clicked into a java file?

Comment: Its a table of 2X2. The first row holds the titles. The second row has a value and a button. On clicking the button in column 2, I want to invoke a java class file which will use the value in column 1 of the same row where the button was clicked.

Comment: simple, when draw you html, draw the value of column one in column two too, for example in onclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to call your function(I suggest you put the table in a form).

```
<tr>
 <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
    <% if (rs.getString(3).contains("s")) {%>
    <%request.getSession().setAttribute("PassFID", rs.getString(7));%>
 <td><input type="button" value='Generate Key' onclick="onclick="somefunction(<%=rs.getString(7)%>);"></input></td>
  <%} 
 else {%>
 <td></td>                                            
 <%}%>
```

and then use a JS like below to pass the value to another jsp page. There on you can do whatever you like with this value.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function somefunction(id){
        var f = document.form;
        f.method="post";
        f.action='somepage.jsp?id='+id;
        f.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i want to pass it to my java class file. how do i do that? and also because the buttons are created in a loop, there needs to be a way to identify which button in which row is clicked so as to pass the respective row value.

Comment: @user3575849 I had a pretty similar problem and I was working with struts 1.3 and couldn't generate dynamic functions. So this was the method I used. Passed the value to another page and put in an input text, named it and auto submit the form to actionclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
   <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
        <% if (rs.getString(3).contains("s")) {%>
        <%request.getSession().setAttribute("PassFID", rs.getString(7));%>
   <td><input type="button" value='Generate Key' onclick="yourFunction(<%=rs.getString(7)%>)"></input></td>
   <%} else {%>
   <td></td>                                            
   <%}%>
 </tr>
```

Comment: same thing. in my function, i need to call my java class file somehow? or do i need to call the function in my java class file directly here. In the latter case, it becomes more complicated as my function has httprequest and httpresponse as parameters so not sure what to pass as arguments here in the onclick operation.